# CORS Angular/PHP Slim Framework

Tags: php, angularjs, cors, slim

I have been trying to find a solution to enable cors on my angular application served by a PHP with Slim API Framework.

The API is located at domain.com and the angular application at mobile.domain.com. Plus, I am not using backend to render angular first route, but pure nginx html config.

I have tried to set allow origin , allow methodson the API /login GET/, however whenever I send the request I obtain this response:

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Could someone give me some direction?

Answer (score 1):

complete solution

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
return $response;
});
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
$response = $next($req, $res);
return $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://mysite')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});
```

[from](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/enable-cors.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the CORS header to your response to allow your app accessing the backend.

```php
$app->add(function($req, $res, $next){
    $res = $res->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'mobile.domain.com');

    return $next($req, $res);
});
```